# High fuel consumption

Tags: motorcycle, repair, fuel-consumption, mileage, bajaj

I own a bajaj ct100b motorcycle,it should give me an average of about 70+ kmpl but I'm only able to eke out 40-45kmpl ,i tried taking it to service,tuning the carbs,there was a fuel tank leak and got that sorted out,the spark plug looks fine,does anyone have any idea? A suggestion? Pls lmk thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you drive the bike regularly at 55 kmph, 45 kmpl is normal for that bike (see [here](https://www.mouthshut.com/bikes/Bajaj-CT-100B-reviews-925837282)).  Try oiling the chain and inflating the tires to the proper pressure.

Change the crankcase oil.  Add [Engine Restore](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/engine-restorer-lubricant-restore-9oz266ml-res-00009-i1399490371-s5202074590.html?c=&channelLpJumpArgs=&clickTrackInfo=query%253Aengine%252Brestore%253Bnid%253A1399490371%253Bsrc%253ALazadaMainSrp%253Brn%253Ae9e10f8baf95a3d2ebd3cbaa31661b61%253Bregion%253Aph%253Bsku%253A1399490371_PH%253Bprice%253A980%253Bclient%253Adesktop%253Bsupplier_id%253A500163945321%253Bbiz_source%253Ah5_internal%253Bslot%253A1%253Butlog_bucket_id%253A470687%253Basc_category_id%253A23130%253Bitem_id%253A1399490371%253Bsku_id%253A5202074590%253Bshop_id%253A1529734&fastshipping=0&freeshipping=1&fs_ab=2&fuse_fs=&lang=en&location=Metro%20Manila&price=9.8E%202&priceCompare=skuId%3A5202074590%3Bsource%3Alazada-search-voucher%3Bsn%3Ae9e10f8baf95a3d2ebd3cbaa31661b61%3BunionTrace%3A21010c9317100448066714240e09db%3BoriginPrice%3A98000%3BvoucherPrice%3A98000%3BdisplayPrice%3A98000%3BsinglePromotionId%3A-1%3BsingleToolCode%3A-1%3BvoucherPricePlugin%3A1%3BbuyerId%3A0%3Btimestamp%3A1710044807056&ratingscore=4.9375&request_id=e9e10f8baf95a3d2ebd3cbaa31661b61&review=16&sale=49&search=1&source=search&spm=a2o4l.searchlist.list.1&stock=1) to the fresh oil, one oz. per liter of oil.

Add [BG 44k](https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/bg-44k-fuel-system-cleaner-fi-cleaning-i4094574161-s22513650579.html?c=&channelLpJumpArgs=&clickTrackInfo=query%253Abg%252B44k%253Bnid%253A4094574161%253Bsrc%253ALazadaMainSrp%253Brn%253A8a019f5d0a115aaf43edfce44eeff75a%253Bregion%253Aph%253Bsku%253A4094574161_PH%253Bprice%253A230%253Bclient%253Adesktop%253Bsupplier_id%253A500558592222%253Bbiz_source%253Ah5_internal%253Bslot%253A1%253Butlog_bucket_id%253A470687%253Basc_category_id%253A23124%253Bitem_id%253A4094574161%253Bsku_id%253A22513650579%253Bshop_id%253A4737626&fastshipping=0&freeshipping=1&fs_ab=2&fuse_fs=&lang=en&location=Laguna&price=2.3E%202&priceCompare=skuId%3A22513650579%3Bsource%3Alazada-search-voucher%3Bsn%3A8a019f5d0a115aaf43edfce44eeff75a%3BunionTrace%3A2102fcc517100449381977499e739e%3BoriginPrice%3A23000%3BvoucherPrice%3A23000%3BdisplayPrice%3A23000%3BsinglePromotionId%3A-1%3BsingleToolCode%3A-1%3BvoucherPricePlugin%3A1%3BbuyerId%3A0%3Btimestamp%3A1710044938598&ratingscore=4.333333333333333&request_id=8a019f5d0a115aaf43edfce44eeff75a&review=2&sale=27&search=1&source=search&spm=a2o4l.searchlist.list.1&stock=1) to the gas tank.  Drive bike vigorously.

Change the air filter if you have not done so already.